# After Updating to Groovy 3.0.5 Jasper-Reports compiled with Groovy won't compile

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports

I updated Groovy from 2.5.10 to 3.0.5 and the Jasper-Reports that are generated using groovy (language="groovy") and use groovy syntax won't compile anymore. I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Failed to link net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/JRGroovyCompiler$ClassCollector (Module "xxx.ear" from Service Module Loader): class net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler$ClassCollector has interface org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ClassgenCallback as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) ~[?:?]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116) ~[?:?]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JRGroovyCompiler.compileUnits(JRGroovyCompiler.java:115) ~[jasperreports-6.13.0.jar:6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:226) ~[jasperreports-6.13.0.jar:6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:358) ~[jasperreports-6.13.0.jar:6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToStream(JasperCompileManager.java:327) ~[jasperreports-6.13.0.jar:6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToStream(JasperCompileManager.java:310) ~[jasperreports-6.13.0.jar:6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToStream(JasperCompileManager.java:588) ~[jasperreports-6.13.0.jar:6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05]
    at
```

I'm using jasperreports version 6.13.0 (newest version) that should work with groovy 3.0.5. When I switch back to groovy 2.5.10 everything works fine.

Anyone had the same problem? Is it a Problem in JasperCompiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JasperReports 6.13.0 does **not** work with Groovy 3.x.  It lists Groovy 2.4.16 as dependency, see [here](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05/jasperreports/pom.xml#L188).

Groovy 3.x support will probably come in a future JasperReports version, but until then the only thing that you can do is to manually patch the JasperReports code to work with Groovy 3.x.  The only code change (other than upgrading the dependency version) is to change `extends` into `implements` at [this line](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/JRGroovyCompiler.java#L157) (as `CompilationUnit.ClassgenCallback` changed from an abstract class into an interface in Groovy 3.x).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use mvnrepository.com to check for libary updates. It says that https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.13.0 can support groovy-all 3.0.5. Is it wrong?

Comment: As far as I can see, the "Updates" column on mvnrepository.com simply shows the latest version of that dependency.  It doesn't imply in any way that the artifact that you are viewing is compatible with the latest versions of its dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

JasperReports were upgraded to 6.17.0 in May 2021. The new version works with Groovy 3.